# How do I go about making an SVG image accessible to screen readers by using the aria-* attributes?

Tags: xml, svg, text, accessibility, wai-aria

I've been creating diagrams using Inkscape and Draw.io and exporting them to SVG files. I'd like to make the text in the SVG files selectable on a web page, or, failing that, at least accessible to screen readers. The problem I'm having is that using the aria-* attributes seem to do nothing for the screen reader ( I've been testing it with JAWS ). I need some help as I don't really know what I'm doing with respect to the aria-* accessibility attributes and I haven't been able to find a concise explanation -- just the w3c spec.

I've tried grouping elements and giving them aria-label attributes but they're not picked up by the screen reader.

```
<g aria-label="R1 register"> ... <text aria-label="Nibble zero">0</text><text aria-label="Nibble one">1</text> ... </g>
```

The expected results would be the screen reader reading the aria-label attributes, but, the last time I tested it, JAWS didn't even read anything within the SVG image file.

Answer (score 2):

There is plenty of information out there on adding aria attributes to SVGs and which ones work with which browsers.

Here are some pages to start with:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/struct.html#WAIARIAAttributes
- https://w3c.github.io/svg-aam/
- https://css-tricks.com/accessible-svgs/
- https://weboverhauls.github.io/demos/svg/
- https://www.deque.com/blog/creating-accessible-svgs/

Comment: I've already read the CSS-Tricks article before I posted my question, but it didn't help my problem. As for the other links you reference, they might be on accessibility for the web, but the articles are not accessible to a general audience not familiar with the topic -- I find them to be tedious and unenlightening reading. What you could do is give me an example or modify my code so that it works instead of just directing me to a bunch of links.

Comment: I don't have a screen reader installed, but my understanding is that it should be working. At least for inline SVG files.  I just realised you don't actually say whether your SVG files are inline, or embedded (with an `<img>` etc).  If you aren't already, use inlined SVG code.  External (via `<img>`) won't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, since the image is in a Wikipedia article, I can only link to it via an img element -- I can't make it inline. Also, apparently some screen readers are supposed to be able to deal with non-inline linked SVGs, but it sounds like you're saying that it shouldn't work :/

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR I am considering just putting all my label info into one `aria-label` on the `svg` element.

So far I am finding `aria-label` on `g` tags (with NVDA  + Chrome  + Win10) are not read out. The same `aria-label` applied to the `svg` element itself *is* read out.

At the moment I am assuming (some/most?) screen readers do not recognize `g` with `aria-label`, even though it is [a valid attribute for the `g` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g#aria_attributes).

Still googling this; it's one of those searches which is tricky, given I am mostly searching for *'g'* o_O

So I am considering a fallback of just putting all my label info into one `aria-label` on the `svg` element.

I would like to see some more authoritative views on the use of `aria-label` and `g`.

Comment: Update: (1) ensure `role="img"` is used on the SVG if you want to try to use `aria-label` on `g` elements. (2) I have it on good authority that for `g` elements buried deep in a "large" `svg`, *'[screen reader] results are a lot less certain'*. So I am favouring the fallback I mentioned.

Comment: Based on https://css-tricks.com/accessible-svgs/#aa-2-lets-make-it-accessible I managed to get the nested `<g>` screen readable by making sure that all the parent `<g>`s had `role="group"` set.